# Is it correct to say that inertia is the centrifugal force in a turn?

Tags: aerodynamics

I came to this thinking using the law of inertia. If the centripetal force (aka. horizontal component of lift) is suddenly removed, the airplane will continue on its straight-line path. My additional thinking is the airplane wants to remain straight and level, it is the (unbalanced) horizontal component of lift that opposes it.

Comment: This question is entirely about physics, not aviation.

Comment: @Ralph, then so too is just about every question on this site about how airplanes turn, or balance of forces in a climb, or...

Comment: I said the word airplane tho

Comment: @RalphJ Physics is what makes aeroplanes fly. Let's delete all questions then, showing banking aircraft, aircraft in a climb, anything with flight dynamics since that is physics...

Comment: "I said the word airplane tho" ... okay, well, as long as we're talking about Physics 101 using ***an airplane*** as the turning object, it must be aviation related.  Is that all that's required to be on-topic here, "airplane"?  `So if airplane #1 leaves city AAA flying toward city BBB at 490 knots, and airplane #2 leaves BBB flying toward AAA at 370 knots, and they meet 3 hours and 20 minutes later, how far apart are AAA and BBB?` That question has ***two*** airplanes in it, so it must _certainly_ be on-topic for Av.SE, right?

Answer (score 3):

It's a convoluted way to think about it, but yes, the "fictitious force" commonly called centrifugal force is merely the effect of inertia, which is offset by centripetal force to create a curved path.

Comment: Oh the questions I can cook up when I ready my aerodynamics textbook. Thank you for the input!

Comment: A sympathetic commentator might call it a virtual force rather than a fictitious one.

Comment: @Frog Just quoting my high school physics teacher, from 1974.